# Lotus Notes 9 - is it possible to hide the preview pane when scrolling between search results in the calendar?

Tags: lotus-notes, hcl-notes

In Lotus Notes 9 is it possible to hide the preview pane when scrolling between search results in the Lotus Notes calendar?
I choose Show -> Hide Preview in oder to hide the preview but each time I use the arrows to scroll through the search results, the preview becomes visible again.

Comment: Are you looking for a programming solution? Your question is worded in a way that seems to have nothing to do with programming, and it doesn't belong on this site if I've read it correctly. As for the actual problem: I don't see that happen. The preview pane just stays hidden for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in lotus notes.

The " Hide Preview " setting does not affect the preview pane when scrolling between search results.

Comment: "The " Hide Preview " setting does not affect the preview pane when scrolling between search results." - this is precisely the problem.

Comment: so are you looking for a programmable solution to the problem? your quest is worded in a way that seemed like it was just asking

Comment: Surely the purpose of the hide preview option is to hide the preview pane?